# Java DatabaseMetaData getIndexInfo Parameter approximate

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-metadata, approximate

I want to check, if a column in a database has a unique-constraint. Therefor this code-snippet is used:

```
try (ResultSet rs = pCon.getMetaData().getIndexInfo(null, pSchema, pTable, true, false))
{

  while (rs.next())
    if (pColumn.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME")))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Now Oracle is used. The tables have many columns and data, so this command take a while. I analyzed it and saw, that this statement on Oracle is executed and takes a long time (21 seconds):

```
analyze table SCHEMA.TABLENAME compute statistics
```

If the method getIndexInfo is called with the parameter approximate = true (`pCon.getMetaData().getIndexInfo(null, pSchema, pTable, true, true)`), this statement isn't executed and everything is fast and performant.

Question: The Java-Doc says, if approximate = true, "result is allowed to reflect approximate or out of data values". So has it an disadvantage, if I use approximate=true?

Comment: What is unclear about the documentation? The disadvantage is that the data might be out of date or only approximate.

Comment: but for my case, only checking if there is a unique constraint, it is recommend to use true or false?

Comment: It should only concern the accuracy of information like cardinality and pages, so using approximate = true should be just fine.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, so i will use this. Of course approximate = false would be better, but the performance on big tables...

Comment: Is there any other possibility to get the unique constraints of a table?

Comment: You could query Oracle's metadata tables directly.

Comment: Yes, but then it's oracle specific. I need something for all dbms.